# can't understand the grad() method in custom Theano Op

Tags: python, theano

when I read the documents about Creating a new Op, I can't understand the grad() in the examples http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/extending_theano.html#example-op-definition. Why do they return `output_grads[0] * 2`  not `2`? and what's `output_grads[0]` represent for?

If output_grads[0] represent a chain derivative with respect to the input x, in the next example http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/extending_theano.html#example-props-definition, why the grad() return `a * output_grads[0] + b` (it should be `self.a * output_grads[0] + self.b`) not `self.a * output_grads[0]`?

How about a more complicated custom Op? Like `y = exp(x1)/(a*(x1**3)+log(x2))`, how to write its grad()? And furthermore, if the inputs are vectors or matrix, how to write the grad()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the extended `.grad()` documentation](http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/op.html#grad) points out, the `output_grads` argument is

[image: dC/df]

(where *f* is one of your `Op`'s outputs and *C* is the cost on which you called `theano.tensor.grad(...)`)

The page also says that the `.grad(...)` method of an `Op` must return

[image: dC/dx=(dC/df)(df/dx)]

(where *x* is an input to your `Op`)

I think the `ax+b` example is just wrong. If you look at the actual code, for example, the [Sigmoid](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/tensor/nnet/sigm.py#L54) or the [XLogX](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/tensor/xlogx.py#L26),
it seems to just implement the chain rule.

---

Disclaimer: I haven't implemented a custom `Op` so far and was looking into this myself and this is how I understood it.

Comment: see also this: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/sandbox/how_to_make_ops.html#grad

Comment: Thanks! LDGN. I think you are right. Output_grads[0] means dC/df, where f is Op’s output, i.e. y1. If there is not next level Op whose inputs include y1, the output_grads [0] is set to 1.